# php multiple str_replace, only the first instance is replaced

Tags: php

the first `str_replace` works fine but the following two do not process. i tested the replacing variables and the replacing string all are present/echo. do I need a unique `$body.` for each?

```
        $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
        $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";    
        $body.= str_replace("%%user%%",$en['user'],$html_content);
        $body.= str_replace("%%confcode%%",$en['confcode'],$html_content);
        $body.= str_replace("%%memb_id%%",$en['memb_id'],$html_content);    
        $body.= "\n\n";
        $body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";
```

Comment: No you don't need unique variables to store the result of str_replace()s results. What does $html_content look like and the values in the $en array?

Comment: $html_content is an html `file $html_content = file_get_contents('/emails/welcome.tpl'); `$en['confcode']` and `$en['memb_id']` are numbers. I did a echo and the values are present.

Comment: So what exactly do the second calls return if you echo them to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Try this instead. I think you might have encounter some issues if you are replacing from a beforehand unreplaced value.

```
$body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";    
$body.= str_replace(array("%%user%%","%%confcode%%","%%memb_id%%"),array($en['user'],$en['confcode'],$en['memb_id']),$html_content);
$body.= "\n\n";
$body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
    $body.= str_replace(
        array(
            "%%user%%",
            "%%confcode%%",
            "%%memb_id%%"
        ), 
        array(
            $en['user'],
            $en['confcode'],
            $en['memb_id']
        ),
        $html_content
    );
```

instead of

```
    $body.= str_replace("%%user%%",$en['user'],$html_content);
    $body.= str_replace("%%confcode%%",$en['confcode'],$html_content);
    $body.= str_replace("%%memb_id%%",$en['memb_id'],$html_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to replace ALL Strings within the same `$html_content`?

There fore you should call `replace` on the already processed strings in order to get them all working:

```
    $body.= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
    $body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";    
    $html_content= str_replace("%%user%%",$en['user'],$html_content);
    $html_content= str_replace("%%confcode%%",$en['confcode'],$html_content);
    $body.= str_replace("%%memb_id%%",$en['memb_id'],$html_content);    
    $body.= "\n\n";
    $body.= "--$mime_boundary--\n";
```

Note, that this will change your `$html_content`. If thats not desired, use another variable to assign the outcome, or the solution from Mark Baker.